# Not able to run my Spring Boot WAR file in docker container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

### Here is my Dockerfile:

FROM tomcat:8.0-alpine

RUN rm -rf /Users/firstname.lastname/Desktop/Backup/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/webapps/*

ADD ./target/restfullapi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /Users/firstname.lastname/Desktop/Backup/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/webapps/restfullapi.war

EXPOSE 8089

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

---

Once I build the .war file I do the following steps:

> docker build -t restfullapi.war .
>   docker run -d -p 8085:8089 restfullapi.war
>   Now when I open localhost:8085 I am able to see only tomcat home page which is correct, but the problem is If I try to access -->> localhost:8085/restfullapi/movies I get 404 error.

and here is my pom.xml

---

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.dev.movies
    restfullapi
    war
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    RestFulAPI Maven Webapp
    http://maven.apache.org
    
        
            junit
            junit
            3.8.1
            test

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>restfullapi</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: why do you want to run a Spring Boot app as Tomcat WAR?

Comment: Hi @BeppeC,requirement was to run my application in Docker

Comment: You can Dockerise the SpringBoot application (without Tomcat) creating the  jar will all dependencies and run on top of the embedded Tomcat

Comment: @Beppe C  I am curious to know about why do we use >jar and .war files ? is there a huge difference of running them in docker? I mean what happens when I use .jar & what happens when I use .war file in docker?

Comment: The final result  is the same but to run a WAR you need a container (Tomcat) so your architecture would be more complicated and relying on Tomcat. SpringBoot can run using the embedded container (still Tomcat) which you dont need to configure or maintain, simplify the deployment

Answer (score 0):

You can run a SpringBoot application in Docker using the default embedded Tomcat. This avoids the need to create a WAR file and provide Tomcat yourself.

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:latest

RUN mkdir -p /software/app

ADD target/restfullapi.jar /software/app/restfullapi.jar

ENV port=8888

CMD java -jar /software/app/restfullapi.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=${SPRING_ACTIVE_PROFILE}
```